# JSF View Scope browser back button issue

Tags: jsf-2

I have a simple page with one field and after successful submission it is redirected to second page, upon unsuccessful submission user stays on same.  I am using `ViewScoped` bean so that the bean is destroyed after successful submission.

Here is the issue,  upon unsuccessful submission, user stays on same view, thereby nothing is cleared out.  Now if the user clicks on `Home` button, he is redirected to home page, if I click on browser back button, my browser is giving a warning message about resubmission.  If I click browser `ReSend` popup button all previous values in view are resubmitted.  As per View scope, it should have been cleared out.  What am I missing?

`index.xhtml`

```
<h:form>
<h:commandButton type="submit" value="Home" action="#{app.toHome()}" />
<br/>
First Name: <h:inputText value="#{app.firstName}" autocomplete="off"/>
<br/>            
<h:commandButton type="submit" value="Submit" action="#{app.doSubmit()}" />
<br/>
<h:messages globalOnly="true" layout="table" />
```

`App.java`

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class App implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5027458534459958194L;
private String firstName;
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String doSubmit() {
    Random r = new Random();
    if (r.nextInt() % 2 == 0) {
        return "/second.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    } else {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Failed for some reason", "Failed for some reason"));
        return null;
    }
}
public String toHome() {
    return "/home.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

}

`MyFilter.java`

```
if (!req.getRequestURI().startsWith(req.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)) { // Skip JSF resources (CSS/JS/Images/etc)
        res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
        res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        res.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.

    }
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but I strongly suggest to just use `<h:button outcome="home" value="Home" />` for the navigation.

Comment: did you try using `f:ajax` for doSubmit() button? with ajax this problem should not occur.

Comment: I tried both options, none of them worked.